Initially, Ganesha was the creator of obstacles. Since when has Ganesha become the remover of obstacles?
An interesting narrative, where Ganesha acted as the creator of obstacles is mentioned in the Siva Purana.
Siva Purana, Kotirudra Samhita, Chapter 25
Near Brahmagiri mountain Sage Gautama and his wife Ahalya used to live. There was a prolonged drought in that area. So, everybody left the place. Gautama did penance and Varuna appeared and created a perennial source of water. The other sages and their wives also came back. However, one day there was a quarrel among the wives of sages regarding who would take the water first. The crooked wives of other sages complained to their husbands that Gautama's wife did not let them take water (which was wrong; they were creating trouble). Anyway, under the influence of the wives, the sages were determined to create impediments for Gautama. They invoked Ganesha.

Angry and wicked in intelligence, they worshipped Ganesha with many kinds of offerings, desiring to create impediments for Goutama. Ganeshvara was pleased and appeared before them.

Sages asked for a boon that Ganesha should help them to expel Sage Gautama from that place. Ganesha agreed.

Ganesha assumed the form of a feeble cow and went there. O supreme among sages! As a result of the boon, he went there, with his body trembling, and started to eat the vrihi and barley. As a result of destiny, Goutama arrived there at the time. The compassionate one tried to restrain the cow with a blade of grass. Touched by the blade of grass, the cow fell down on the ground and died instantly, while the rishi looked on.

Other sages accused Gautama of committing the sin of killing a cow. They threw stones at him and reprimanded his wife Ahalya too.

Goutama spoke the following words. “O sages! I will leave this place and go and reside somewhere else.” Saying this, Goutama left that spot. He took their permission and went and made his hermitage at a place that was one krosha away.

His right to do Vedic rituals was taken away. Also, he was forced to do a Prayaschitta. So, Gautama's life was made miserable.
So, the point is Ganesha created impediments, and he was invoked to do exactly that. So he acted as the creator of obstacles, not Bighnahantri (remover of obstacles).
However, later as we all know he is worshipped as the remover of obstacles. Since when did he become the remover of obstacles and what was the story behind that?
